# WIX Setup Project - Could not load file or assembly GMap.net

Tags: c#, wix, setup-project, gmap.net, wix4

I have a windows form app that I have deployed using a WIX4 Setup project.

The app installs fine, but I am getting the following error message when opening it (I added some exception handling to show the error message).

[image]

I used a visual studio set up project originally and did not get the issue when running, so something is different with WIX but I need to be able to run custom actions prior to install so Wix seems to be the only option.

Has anyone come across this and know how to resolve?

I have tried various versions of GMap.

cheers.

Comment: Is the relevant GMap assembly appearing in your installation folder after running your MSI? Does your project include a reference to this assembly? Do you have `Copy Local` explicitly to `true` (i.e. is `<Private>True</Private>` included in the assembly's reference element in the project file)?